# Getting minWidth (appwidget-provider) across all devices, phones and tablets

Tags: android, android-widget

My android application (Banner) uses widgets sizes from 1x1 to 8x1. I'm getting annoyed with trying to get the magic minWidth set in the XML `appwidget-provider` files.

Old school method to get widget minimum size was something like [74 x (n) - 2]. Now the method is [70 x (n) - 30]. Neither of these work well past 3x1 widgets. 4x1 if set correctly on a phone usually becomes a 3x1 widget on tablets because of dpi/density/size, etc.

So I ended up placing `xml` files as such to adjust width as needed. However, I'm really only guessing that the increased minWidth works with all devices as I only tested on my own tablet.

So my question is this... has anyone figured out the BEST minWidths or methods for making widgets on different device sizes, etc?

[image]

Comment: i know this is old, but check out this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10008521/appwidget-size-calculation